# How to find the average number in an array that has already been constructed

Tags: java, arrays, instance

How could I write a method that returns the average weight of an array boxes. Assume that the array boxes has been constructed. Also can not assume that every element of the array has been constructed. If the array is empty the method should return 0.0. This is what I have at the moment but I am very lost.

```
public class Question03 {
    //The array of boxes to be used by the method "getAverageWeight()"
    //This property is public for testing purposes
    public Box[] boxes;
    
    public double getAverageWeight()
    {
        int h = boxes.length;
        double avg = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0;i<boxes.length;i++)
        {
            if(boxes[i] == null)
            {
                h--;
            }
        }
        return avg;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question, along with your other one on doing arithmetic with arrays, make me think you're asking SO to help you do your homework. Check out the guidance for how to do that properly here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. Basically, try something first and then post a question about how what you tried isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy if your using streams. `average()` returns an `OptionalDouble` so you can provide a default if the array is empty.

```
Box[] boxes =
        { new Box(10), new Box(20), null, null, new Box(30) };

double avg = Arrays.stream(boxes).filter(obj -> obj != null)
        .mapToDouble(Box::getWeight).average().orElse(0.);
System.out.println("Avg weight = " + avg);
```

Prints

```
Avg weight = 20.0
```

or more traditonally

```
double sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (Box b : boxes) {
   if (b != null) {
      sum += b.getWeight();
      count++;
    }
}    
System.out.println("Avg weight = " + (sum/count));
```

Prints

```
Avg weight = 20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

"Continue" if its not constructed and make sure that you sum the weights

Then you can simple return sum of all weights devided by the number of constructed boxes

I would also suggest that you make sure to avoid devide by 0
-> simple add check if h==0 and return 0 instead

```
public double getAverageWeight()
    {
        
        
        int h = boxes.length;
        double sumWeight=0.0;
        for(int i = 0;i<boxes.length;i++)
        {
            if(boxes[i] == null)
            {
                h--;
                continue;
            }
            sumWeight+=boxes[i].getWeight();
        }

        return sumWeight/h;
    }
```

Comment: this works but how would I make it so if the value was null in the array it would be set to 0.0?

Comment: You could simple create a new box and set value to 0.0 inside if condition
boxes[i]=new Box(0.0);
h--;
continue;

Comment: It would be much nicer to set h=0; check for != null, put the sum+ inside the if, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer working with Streams over Loops, then this would be working implementation:

```
public double getAverageWeight(Box[] boxes) {

    Collection<Box> noNulls = Arrays.stream(boxes)
                                    .filter(b -> b != null)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (noNulls.isEmpty()) {
        return 0.0d;
    }
    
    double sum = noNulls.stream().map(b -> b.getWeight()).reduce(0.0d, (a,b) -> a+b);
    return sum / noNulls.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

1. Return `0` if the array is `null` or empty.
2. Initialize a variable (e.g. `h` in the code shown below) equal to the length of the array and another (e.g. `sum` in the code shown below) equal to `0`. Use the variable, `h` to keep track of non-null elements while `sum` to collect the weight of all non-null elements.
3. While navigating the array, replace a `null` element with an instance of `Box`.
4. Finally, return the average as `sum / h`.

**Demo:**

```
public double getAverageWeight() {
    // If the array is empty the method should return 0.0. 
    if(boxes == null || boxes.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    double sum = 0;
    int h = boxes.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if(boxes[i] != null) {
            sum += boxes[i].weight;// Add the weight of each box to sum
        } else {
            boxes[i] = new Box();// Replace the null element with a Box object
            h--;
        }
    }

    // Return the average by dividing the sum by the count of boxes
    return sum / h;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution would be to use Streams

```
double avg = Arrays.stream(boxes)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .mapToDouble(Box::getWeight)
    .average()
    .orElse(0);
```